# Pasting Excel tables in Thunderbird e-mail client

Tags: excel, thunderbird

When I paste an Excel table in Thunderbird e-mail client (ver 24.2.0) the table looses its formatting. One workaround seems to be that you paste the table from Excel to Word and then paste it in Thunderbird. But this seems a bit odd as Word and Excel are part of the same Office Suite of applications, yet their behavior is strange.

Can anybody shed any light on it?

Comment: Hi! Did you find some other way to copy(from Excel)-paste(Thunderbird New Message) with borders to be visible?

Answer (score 5):

Copy from Excel,
Paste into word -> Paste Options -> Keep Source formatting, 
then highlight the table, Go to Design -> on the right, Increase the "Line Weight" to a minimum of 1 point, then click on "Borders" and select "All Borders"

Now copy this table and paste it in your Email. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to copy excel tables as they are, in Thunderbird is to first copy the table to Word, and then recopy and paste within html email. 
Colors, lines, format are kept as they are...

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround you can do entirely within Excel is copy the cells for your table, pasted as a picture in Excel and then copy/cut the picture from Excel and then paste to Thunderbird.  You lose the ability to edit in place in Thunderbird, and increase the size of the email but you keep all the formatting from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

So far,the best solution is paste the table into Word and then copy from there.

This is a bug from 2003 [Reference Link](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195012)，but didn‘t fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the table as it is in mail from excel, then go to

**Format --> Table --> Table Properties**

**In Borders & Spacing, keep the *Borders as- 1 or 2 pixels*.**

It is working 100%

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in thunderbird. I overcome this by using LibreOffice (or open office) spreadsheet. Formatting is *not* lost when we copy from Libreoffice Calc. Thunderbird development is a bit lousy :-). Keeping this bug open for long time.

Answer (score 0):

try to use "Text To column" function under the "DATA"  TAB

it will make the column suitable to be pasted as a text